# "contentful" command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, contentful

I am following this [getting started guide](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/integrate-contentful-with-vue-and-nuxt/) and I ran into this issue despite running `brew upgrade node` and having the `contentful-cli` tool install where it's supposed to install. Any ideas why this would happen?

```
~/Development/misc-dev/travel-blog(master):0 npm i -g contentful-cli  
npm WARN deprecated joi@13.7.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@5.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated joi@10.6.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated items@2.1.2: This module has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version of hapi to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.14.0/bin/contentful -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.14.0/lib/node_modules/contentful-cli/bin/contentful.js

> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.14.0/lib/node_modules/contentful-cli/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall

+ contentful-cli@0.26.4
added 490 packages from 231 contributors in 20.129s

~/Development/misc-dev/travel-blog(master):0 contentful --help      
zsh: command not found: contentful
```

Comment: Type `npm bin` and check if the path is part of your `$PATH`.

Comment: @Tico it seems like it's not part of $PATH. The value is this: `/Users/michael/Development/misc-dev/travel-blog/node_modules/.bin` How come it's not part of `$PATH`?

Comment: `which npm` outputs `/usr/local/bin/npm` - this is expected right? are there two npm installs or something?

Comment: `npm bin` displays the folder where `npm` will install executables. `which npm` displays the location of `npm` itself.

Comment: Interesting so it seems `npm install -g <package>` doesn't actually install globally.. would you happen to know why? Is there like a global `.npm.config` file somewhere?

Comment: Add `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/michael/Development/misc-dev/travel-blog/node_modules/.bin"` to your `.zshrc` file. Save it and type `source .zshrc` (or just reopen the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.14.0/bin:$PATH"` to my `.zshrc` file because `brew` installed node packages were not part of my `$PATH` variable. Running `npm bin -g` helped find me where my global packages are installed and confirmed this for me. Thank you @Tico for the guidance.

Comment: I'm on windows and can't seem to locate any .zshrc file. I also have no appdata/local/yarn/config folder. Wat do?

Comment: `.zshrc` is just the config file for my "zsh" terminal so unless you have "zsh" installed, it won't exist. "Zsh" is like a custom version of a Bash terminal. Regarding `yarn`, you will need to set up yarn in a windows env (I'm sure there are guides for this).